# Detecting 2G and 3G on an iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios7, nsurlconnection, xcode5, nsurlrequest

I am currently using apples Reachability example to detect for an available connection but what I need is to be able to detect if a WWAN connection is 2G or 3G. For the purposes of the application downloading a file to determine signal speed is not a solution and using the status bar to read the connection has also been dismissed.

I am currently using MKNetworkKit to handle my requests.

Any help is appreciated
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SCNetworkReachability` interface can help you with that. Basically, you create a so-called reachability reference and then call `SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags` on it to get information about the connection.

The returned flags include `kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN`, which tells you whether you are connected via WiFi or the cell network. AFAIK it cannot be used to tell the difference between 2G and 3G, though.

See [Apple's Reachability sample app](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) for an implementation. In most cases, you should be able to directly use the included Reachability class in your project.

Comment: Short answer of the above, **NO** you can not detect the network type!

Answer (score 1):

You can't detect the network type, Reachability can manage only these network status:

```
typedef enum
{
    // Apple NetworkStatus Compatible Names.
    NotReachable = 0,      // No connection
    ReachableViaWiFi = 2,  // Connecte on WIFI
    ReachableViaWWAN = 1   // Connected on 2G, 3G or 4G network.
} NetworkStatus;
```